# How to use internal namespace in javascript moduler pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

i have 2 .js utility files. and im using module pattern like below. MODULE1 & MODULE2 are global namespaces. In addition internally both the .js files are using same variable name for namespace i.e **"mynamespace"**
i would like to know that would cause any issue having internal namespace name same in both the modules.

**1.js**

```
var MODULE1 = (function () {
    var mynamespace = {};

    privateVariable = 1;

    function privateMethod() {
    // ...
    }

    mynamespace .Init = function () {
    // ...
   };

    return mynamespace ;
 }());
```

**2.js**

```
var MODULE2 = (function () {
   var mynamespace = {};    

   privateVariable = 1;

   function privateMethod() {
    // ...
   }

   mynamespace.Init = function () {
    // ...
   };

   return mynamespace;
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because mynamesapce variable is only defined in the local scope of each function.

It would cause you trouble if mynamespace was global, which isn't the case